# How to safely split a power supply into two?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply

I have 6AA batteries connected to [this UBEC](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00D75K3L6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), giving me 5V 5A. Now I have an Arduino Mega and [this SIM900 GPRS shield](http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=SIM900_GPRS/GSM_Shield) which I need to power. As I have a steady 5V I can power the Arduino through the 5V pin, however the SIM900 shield requires a lot of current and therefore cannot be powered via the Arduino. In this case I need to power them from the same power source, but powering them separately.

Is there a safe way to power them something like the image below? As the two shields are stacked on top of each other, does this cause an issue (or does it just give them both a common ground?)?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.

Comment: *the SIM900 shield requires a lot of current and therefore cannot be powered via the Arduino.* Why not ? The 5 V does not come from the Arduino, the 5 V comes from the DCDC converter (I mean the UBEC). So as long as you make a direct connection of the 5 V and GND between the Arduino and the GPRS shield, the power will **only pass through** the Arduino. And the GPRS shield only needs 450 mA max, that is not too much.

Comment: It ought to be much easier.  Just connect the 6AA batteries to the VIN on the Arduino.  The Arduino has its own regulator, and passes the VIN straight to the SIM900.  The SIM900 also has its own regulator and operates off of VIN.  So, the Arduino doesn't really power the SIM900, it just passes the VIN through.  The UBEC is just a waste of power, and a complication.

Comment: I have been led to believe that if I supply 5V to the arduino and shield via the 5V pin, the current is limited to something like 500mA?
Does the VIN pin not send power through the Arduino regulator and then to the shields, reducing the supplied 5v?

Comment: No, the VIN pin (the barrel jack) sends power to the Arduino's 5V regulator, but also passes it straight through to the VIN pin on the SIM9000.  Check the schematics of both boards.

Comment: Make sure to jumper select the Arduino power to run off of the internal regulator.

Comment: Isn't the UBEC better in the sense that it more efficient than using the Arduinos voltage regulator? I got the UBEC to avoid having to use the built in voltage reg.

Comment: Is using the UBEC regulated 5V into the 5v arduino pin doing the same as VIN just without the arduino's voltage regulator (as in still simply passing the 5V and 5A up to the shield)?